# Empty result on native SQL query on Hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate

I am trying to develop a simple method to execute sql queries on my application so I can use native sql for certain things.
This is the method I have:

```
Session session = getReportCsvMgr().getHibernateSession();
session.beginTransaction();
String sql = String.format("select USER_ID from Users where accountid = 'testaaa'");
Object o = session.createSQLQuery(sql).list();
System.out.println(o.toString());

session.close();
```

I do not get any errors but somehow the object o is empty and the sysout just prints [].
I debugged and the session works. I tested changing the name of the table and indeed it said "table does not exist". I also tried with and update statement, no errors but it does nothing.
Can anybody tell me what I need to do?

Thanks!

Comment: The obvious reason: you don't have a row in the database where the condition in the `where` clause is true

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
Object o = session.createSQLQuery(sql).list();
```

to:

```
List<Integer> o = session.createSQLQuery(sql).list();
```

it the USER_ID is integer or to:

```
List<String> o = session.createSQLQuery(sql).list();
```

if the USER_ID is string.

Moreover in a query you have not passed params so you can change:

```
String sql = String.format("select USER_ID from Users where accountid = 'testaaa'");
```

to simple:

```
String sql = "select USER_ID from Users where accountid = 'testaaa'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use `.uniqueResult()` instead of `.list()` if it only returns one row or change the return type to `List<Object[]>`